# On mvn assembly

Tags: maven

The following currently takes my dependencies and places them into newly created lib directory.

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

**Question: How can i change that to exclude 1 file?**

The following does not work:

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>my_program-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/including-and-excluding-artifacts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the convention:

```
<exclude>groupId:artifactId</exclude>
```

So if you had for example:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

To exclude it:

```
<exclude>org.springframework:spring-jdbc</exclude>
```

Comment: Is there a generic way to describe "that what you are building". In other words, the jar that i am building now should never be in `lib` but always be in `bin`

Comment: you can use the project properties: ${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}